# Merge two data frame with few different columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to merge several DataFrames having few different columns. 
Suppose ,

- DataFrame A has 3 columns: Column_1, Column_2, Column 3
- DataFrame B has 3 columns: Column_1, Columns_2, Column_4
- DataFrame C has 3 Columns: Column_1, Column_2, Column_5

I want to merge these DataFrames such that I get a DataFrame like :

Column_1, Column_2, Column_3, Column_4 Column_5

number of DataFrames may increase. Is there any way to get this merge ? such that for a particular Column_1 Column_2 combination i get the values for other three columns in same row, and if for a particular combination of Column_1 Column_2 there is no data in some Columns then it should show null there.

DataFrame A:

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
   1        x        abc
   2        y        def
```

DataFrame B:

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_4
   1        x        xyz
   2        y        www
   3        z        sdf
```

The merge of A and B :

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4
   1        x        abc     xyz
   2        y        def     www
   3        z        null    sdf
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll be needing to perform an *outer join* using a sequence of columns as keys.

I have used the data provided in your question to illustrate how it is done with an example :

```scala
scala> val df1 = Seq((1,"x","abc"),(2,"y","def")).toDF("Column_1","Column_2","Column_3")
// df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Column_1: int, Column_2: string, Column_3: string]

scala> val df2 = Seq((1,"x","xyz"),(2,"y","www"),(3,"z","sdf")).toDF("Column_1","Column_2","Column_4")
// df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Column_1: int, Column_2: string, Column_4: string]

scala> val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("Column_1","Column_2"), "outer")
// df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Column_1: int, Column_2: string, Column_3: string, Column_4: string]

scala> df3.show
// +--------+--------+--------+--------+                                           
// |Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|Column_4|
// +--------+--------+--------+--------+
// |       1|       x|     abc|     xyz|
// |       2|       y|     def|     www|
// |       3|       z|    null|     sdf|
// +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

This is called an `equi-join` with another `DataFrame` using the given columns.

It is different from other join functions, the join columns will only appear once in the output, i.e. similar to SQL's `JOIN USING` syntax.

**Note**

Outer equi-joins are available since Spark 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

First use following codes for all three data frames, so that SQL queries can be implemented on dataframes

```scala
DF1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1view")
DF2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2view")
DF3.createOrReplaceTempView("df3view")
```

then use this join command to merge

```scala
val intermediateDF = spark.sql("SELECT a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, b.column4 FROM df1view a leftjoin df2view b on a.column1 = b.column1 and a.column2 = b.column2")`

intermediateDF.createOrReplaceTempView("imDFview")

val resultDF = spark.sql("SELECT a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, a.column4, b.column5 FROM imDFview a leftjoin df3view b on a.column1 = b.column1 and a.column2 = b.column2")
```

these join can also be done together in one join, also since you want all values of column1 and column2,you can use `full outer join` instead of `left join`